# Hide excel ribbon in exisiting workbook

Tags: c#, excel, ribbon

to keep it short. I have an excel workbook were I hide the ribbon with VBA using:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
```

[image]
Now i wrote an application with C# that opens that workbook. The workbook then opens without the ribbon but the space "above" is hidden too. No x, -, etc. in the upper right, it just directly starts with the grid of excel.
[image]
It cannot be closed in the usual way since the buttons are gone.
I would now like to know if I can dismiss the VBA code in the workbook and hide the ribbon with C# code? Or do I have to expand the code in VBA to have the same effect when openend from an C# application. I didn´t expected it to behave that way but I´m a beginner.
Things is I found samples only for the case were the ribbon was added using ribbon xml. I want to do it with an exisiting workbook that only is openend. No modifications, just hide it.
C# code looks like this:

```
namespace opn_excel_1

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string fileExcel;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileExcel = "C:\\Users\\1.0.xlsm";
        excel.Application xlApp;
        excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        xlApp = new excel.Application();
        // open Workbook
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlApp.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

Whats the best solution to solve this problem?

regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your goal is. The VBA code you provide correctly hides the ribbon.
If you want to give the user the possibility to reopen it, you can use

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
```

Here are what you can do programmatically

```
Sub ShowRibbon()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
End Sub

Sub HideRibbon()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
End Sub

Sub MinimizeRibbon()
    CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
End Sub
```

MinimizeRibbon will minimize the ribbon. If you call it when it is minimized, it returns to normal.

Edit: I made some tests with the hide ribbon code at startup and it works as expected.
[image]

The code I used to open Excel and Workbook is:

```
var progId = "Excel.Application";
dynamic xlApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId));
xlApp.Visible = true;
xlApp.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = true;
string fileExcel = @"C:\Users\accogli.davide\Documents\Test.xlsm";
object xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel);
```

I use Activator because I don't have Office integration in Visual Studio.

In the Workbook, I lauch the VBA code at open

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Modulo1.HideRibbon
End Sub
```

And in Modulo1 I have the HideRibbon method

```
Sub HideRibbon()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I added 2 images to better understand the problem. The code in the excel workbook is the same. But when opened with an C# application the upper part is missing (see second image). Like its hidden too. Can´t discribe it better. This way I´m not even able to close excel without using the taskmanager because the close button (x) is hidden as well. I hope you can see what I mean.